# Sudo error message

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I am trying to fix some permission issues on a Debian server. Someone on a team of mine was changing permissions around, and somewhere in the process, things got screwed up. Whenever I sudo now, I get this error message/warning:

```
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040720), should be mode 0700
```

I'm confused by the number in parenthesis. What does this mean? Also, what command was probably run to set such permissions? How should these permissions be set?

The `/var/lib/sudo` permissions are:

```
drwx-w----  5 root     sudo 4096 Feb  4 02:36 sudo
```

Which I understand to mean: This directory is read write executable by root, and writeable by the sudo group, and no privileges for the rest of users. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last three digits of a permission mode are for owner, group, and other users respectively, and are a sum of the following values:

4 is for read (r)

2 is for write (w)

1 is for execute (x)

So if /var/lib/subo is ***720, this means:

- Owner permissions = 7 = 4 + 2 + 1 = read + write + execute
- Group permissions = 2 = write
- Other permissions = 0 = no permissions.

So yes, you are correct in your interpretation of that line of output.

File mode is changed with the `chmod` command

```
chmod MODE FILE
```

Now, the interesting thing is that you can specify MODE as an octal number OR as a more human readable string (read below). To fix the warning you'd `chmod 700 /var/lib/sudo`, or more likely `sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/sudo`.

The more readable form needs a little more explanation, though:

1. Use `u`, `g`, or `o` to indicate user, group, or other
2. Use `+` or `-` to grant or revoke permissions
3. Use `r`, `w`, or `x` for read, write, or execute.

So here that'd be `chmod g-w /var/lib/sudo`, which, in pseudo-English, reads as *change mode: for the group, revoke write, of /var/lib/sudo*.

Answer (score 4):

The 040720 value is the octal representation of the 16-bit value storing the permissions and file type information in an inode (the `st_mode` element of `struct stat`). The 4 least significant (octal) digits represent the permissions and the others the file type.  By inference, `040` means 'directory'.  The 0720 permissions are read, write, execute for user (owner), write for group (which is what is being complained about), and no access for others.  The leading 0 of 0720 means that the setuid, setgid and sticky bits are all zero.

You could fix the error reports by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/sudo
```

You might want to do that recursively (`chmod -R`) but be cautious about making data files executable that should not be.  You might need to fix the owner; the directory is owned correctly by `root`, but you might need to fix up the owner below the directory.  For that, you might use this to set both user (`root`) and group (`sudo`):

```
sudo chown -R root:sudo /var/lib/sudo
```